# How to install nest module from a .tar.gz source file

Tags: python-2.7, installation, pip, nest-simulator

I'm trying to install nest with the command "pip install nest-2.16.0.tar.gz" but get [an error as shown in the attached picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0Ymw.png) The tar file is in the correct directory.

"
ERROR:Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "", line 1, in

### IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\users\steph506\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-ufft6c\setup.py'

ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in ''c:\users\steph506\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-ufft6c\'
"

The PATH variable is set to C:...Python27. Does anyone know what is causing this error, and how I can install the package from the file I have?
Thank you!

BACKGROUND: I specifically need the 2.16.0 version of the nest module. When I do "pip install nest" it finds a 1.* version instead. When I do "pip install nest==2.16.0" it says it can't find that version. So instead I downloaded the nest-2.10.0.tar.gz file directly and I tried to install from that file. I also tried upgrading pip to make sure I had the latest available version.

Comment: There is no version bigger than 1.3 at [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/nest/#history). Where have you got your 2.16? Also please paste error messages as text. Dark red on black with small font is unreadable.

Comment: The latest version is at this link: https://nest-simulator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/download.html

Comment: [Installation Instructions](https://nest-simulator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/index.html) say: **NEST is not supported natively on Microsoft Windows.** However, it is possible to use NEST in Windows using a virtual machine. Other installation instructions are for Debian and MacOS X.